# Plotly Dash App on Kubernetes -- Not loading Javascript

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes, plotly-dash

I'm trying to run Dash app using Flask on my server with Kubernates

```py
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
from flask import Flask

server = Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(name='my-server', server=server)

app.layout = html.Div([
    ....
])


@server.route("/")
def dash_app():
    return app.index()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Obviously have more stuff(like more html and callback functions).
When create a docker image and run it locally, it runs perfectly fine at `127.0.0.1:5000`, though when I push it to my server and run it with kubernates, it gives me the following errors.

```
Refused to execute script from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

And

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: DashRenderer is not defined
```

And stuck with "Loading..." screen.

Any help/insight would be appreciated!
Thanks :)))

Answer (score 0):

hihi,
i have experienced this issue also. After debugging, it was due to browser cannot get those javascript files. Thus, need to let it know where to find them.

Suppose you want to deploy to your k8s at
`<domain-name>/mycooldashboards/dashboard-1`. You can add an env var to the dash deployment as below

```
name: DASH_URL_BASE_PATHNAME
value: /mycooldashboards/dashboard-1/  # needs to end by slash
```

Also, your ingress need to support users to get/post. The path in ingress is like:

```
/mycooldashboards/dashboard-1(/|$)(.*)
```

Then it should work for you.

here is the source of information: https://dash.plotly.com/reference
(just look for DASH_URL_BASE_PATHNAME)